# How can I do something (e.g., replace a string) in all files in a directory and all sub-directories except for one sub-directory?

Tags: find

I am using the following command

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/_backpack.html/_backpack_cal.html/g' {} +
```

I expect all "_backpack.html" strings in my project
to be replaced with `_backpack_cal.html`, and this happens.

However, the problem is that it also edits files in my `.git` directory,
which corrupts Git. 
How can I prevent `find` from touching my `.git` directory
while at the same time working with all the other sub-directories?

Comment: Do you want to omit files in a `.git` directory only, or do you want to omit all hidden files, which traditionally means all files beginning with "." and all files under directories that begin with "." ?

Comment: For the problem I was facing I just wanted to omit .git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use :

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/_backpack.html/_backpack_cal.html/g' {} +
```

I added the `-name .git -prune` section which basically means "if the name of the directory is `.git`, do not process that directory."

Also, please note the added `-o` (meaning `or`) which only executes your statement if the first one is false (ie if the name of the processed file is the `.git` directory).

Of course, you should test this before actually executing the command, by replacing the `-exec ...` part with a `-print`, for example.

Comment: The parentheses are actually optional here.

Comment: @Gilles You are right, the `and` (default) has precedence over the `or`, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude `.git` only:

```
find . ! -path '.git/*' -type f
```

To exclude all hidden files and directories:

```
find . ! -path '*/.*' -type f
```